# how to manage multiple instances of an app in server connecting with multiple clients on diff machines

Tags: c, windows, networking, client-server

I have an application that needs to be paired with a client on a remote machine.  There can be several instances of this application running on the server, each servicing a different client, probably as many as 25-30 pairs.

Each pair of server-client will need to have two tcp connections.  The server app has 2 processes, and each process has its own tcp connection to the client.

- Process A exchanges commands with client
- Process B receives constant video stream from the client.

In addition, there's another tcp connection between each pair Process A/Process B

Commands/Data will flow from as follows:

Client <--> Process A <---> Process B

while video will flow in this direction:

client --> Process B

I need help to determine what is the best way to establish all the tcp connections.  Who sets up listeners? how to determine the ports to be used? etc.

I currently have a single instance of Process A communicating with both Process B and client, but it is all running in one machine, so I am just using "localhost" as my hostname for now.  I am also hardcoding the 2 ports that I am using, so I need to change that as well when I have multiple instances so that each instance uses different ports.

Once Process A makes a connection with Client, it needs to ask the Client for a port so that Process B can make the other connection directly with Client.  Is this a good way to do it, or what is a better way?  How can the client determine what port is available to be used?

Also any help or pointers on how to assign the ports so this can work with multiple instances would be appreciated.

Thanks, please ask any questions about anything that is not clear.

EDIT: Actually process A and process B are two different applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about the application, so it's possible this can be further simplified, but I would do the following:

- Create one or two server processes listening on known ports (you could probably get this down to one, but if you need two, ok I'll explain how to do that).
- If you can get it down to a single server process, it can listen on both ports itself.  Using the `select` call, you can have it monitor for activity on each open file descriptor.  In fact, this is why I think you could do the entire thing with a single process, or a small pool of them.
- Have the client connect to the known port on the server.  Having the server connect to the client will give you trouble when you get into remote networks.  You can always get the server somewhere with port forwarding or in a DMZ, but you can't insist that all of your clients change their network to remove NAT, disable firewalls, or forward ports for your application.
- When the client connects, if you need multiple processes, have the servers establish as open connection to each other before forking so that you can connect them using the known port.
- If you need a separate process, use `fork` to split the processes.  In the child process, you close the file descriptors that are listening on the known ports.  And in the parent process, you close the file descriptors that are connected to the clients in addition to the file descriptors that are connected to the other server process.

Note: this is from a linux background, but I'm pretty sure all of these functions and methods will work on windows.  I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong.  I strongly suggest trying to use `select` to get this down to a single process which will greatly simply your coding.  If you need to make better use of a multi-processor system, then go multi-threaded or have a pool of processes that trade-off the connection handling.  Learning about how file descriptors work after a `fork` will simplify your coding should you need to create multiple processes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually process A and B are two different applications, so there's no parent/child process.  No fork is used.

Comment: you say "Have the client connect to the known port on the server" how would this work when I have several instances of the server apps running. Each instance needs to be on a different port.

Comment: If it's two separate processes, you'll have at least two known ports, proc A and B.  If you can't get proc B down to a single process that listens and forks off children, then for each proc B, I'd have it communicate back to proc A with it's port number that is finds open.  The proc A can send this port number to the client for it's second connection.

Comment: To get an open port, you can give proc B a starting port and in a loop have it try to bind/listen and should it fail, return to the top of the loop and increment the port.